# Find elements belonging together across columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a table of historic changes of a part. Whenever a change is made, the ID of the change and its date are recorded. When the validity of a row is ended, the change/date is recorded in the _B column and a new row is added with the same ID/date in the _A column. A part can be added in several positions (that extra info is left out), that happens in row 4 and 8. The other rows tell the historic trail of changes for each part.

```
# copy-pastable code
bla = pd.DataFrame({'value':{1:1,2:1,3:1,4:2,5:1,6:2,7:99,8:3,9:3,10:99},
 'brte_kema_e': {1: 'ID0',2: 'ID1',3: 'ID2',4: 'ID4',5: 'ID3',6: 'ID5',7: 'ID6', 8: 'ID11',9: 'ID12',10: 'ID10'},
'brte_kemb_e': {1: 'ID1',2: 'ID2',3: 'ID3',4: 'ID5', 5: 'ID6',6: 'ID8',7: ID10',  8: 'ID12',9: 'ID13',10: ''},
  'date_A':{1:pd.datetime(2000,1,1),2:pd.datetime(2000,4,1),3:pd.datetime(2001,1,1), 4:pd.datetime(2000,12,1),5:pd.datetime(2001,6,1),6:pd.datetime(2002,1,1),
           7:pd.datetime(2003,1,1),8:pd.datetime(2009,1,1), 9:pd.datetime(2010,1,1),10:pd.datetime(2004,1,1)},
  'date_B':{1:pd.datetime(2000,4,1),2:pd.datetime(2001,1,1), 3:pd.datetime(2001,6,1), 4:pd.datetime(2002,1,1), 5:pd.datetime(2003,1,1),        6:pd.datetime(2008,1,1), 7:pd.datetime(2004,1,1), 8:pd.datetime(2010,1,1), 9:pd.datetime(2015,1,1),10:""}
   }
 )

    value   ID_A    ID_B    date_A      date_B
1   1       ID0     ID1     2000-01-01  2000-04-01
2   1       ID1     ID2     2000-04-01  2001-01-01
3   1       ID2     ID3     2001-01-01  2001-06-01
4   2       ID4     ID5     2000-12-01  2002-01-01
5   1       ID3     ID6     2001-06-01  2003-01-01
6   2       ID5     ID8     2002-01-01  2008-01-01
7   99      ID6     ID10    2003-01-01  2004-01-01
8   3       ID11    ID12    2009-01-01  2010-01-01
9   3       ID12    ID13    2010-01-01  2015-01-01
10  99      ID10    ""      2004-01-01  NaT
```

I want to find out if and when the change in value (from 1 to 99) for the first part occured. The value of the other two remain at 2 and 3 the whole time.

In order to find the change of the value, I first need to identify which changes belong to the same part. This is graphically shown in the picture, the desired result is shown in the list of lists.

So I get three paths of changes for each part:

```
[['ID0', 'ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID6', 'ID10', 'ID14'],
 ['ID4', 'ID5', 'ID8'],
 ['ID11', 'ID12', 'ID13']]
```

[image]

From there it should be straight forward to find the changed value.

Right now I am looping and appending to lists, which is ugly and slow.

Is there a *pandastic* way of doing it?